# Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread, No context holder available for job scope Spring-Batch

Tags: multithreading, spring-boot, spring-batch

In my Spring batch job, I'm trying to share data between steps using JobExecutionContext, which works only if i keep the steps single threaded as follows:

```
    @EnableTask
    @EnableBatchProcessing
    @Configuration
    @PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})

    public class Config{

    private static final HashMap<String,Object> OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION = null;
    private static final String QUERY = "SELECT * FROM \"Config\"";

    @Autowired
    public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Autowired
    EntityManager em;


    @Autowired
    DataSource dataSource;


    /*Config Step*/

   @Bean
    public JdbcCursorItemReader<BatchConfig> configReader(DataSource dataSource) {
        JdbcCursorItemReader<BatchConfig> config = new JdbcCursorItemReader<>();
            config.setDataSource(dataSource);

            config.setSql(QUERY);
            config.setRowMapper(new BatchRowMapper());

            return config;
    }

    @Bean
    public ItemWriter<BatchConfig> itemWriter() {
        return new ItemWriter<BatchConfig>() {

            private StepExecution stepExecution;

            @Override
            public void write(List<? extends BatchConfig> items) {
                ExecutionContext stepContext = this.stepExecution.getExecutionContext();
                for (BatchConfig item : items) {
                    HashMap<String, Object> table = new HashMap<>();
                    table.put("date", item.getDate_time());
                    table.put("size", item.getSize());
                    System.out.println(table);
                    stepContext.put(item.getName(), table);

                }
            }

            @BeforeStep
            public void saveStepExecution(StepExecution stepExecution) {
                this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
            }
        };
    }

    @Bean
    public Step stepConfig(JdbcCursorItemReader<BatchConfig> configReader) throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("stepConfig")
                .<BatchConfig, BatchConfig>chunk(10)
                .reader(configReader)
                .writer(itemWriter())
                .listener(promotionListener())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExecutionContextPromotionListener promotionListener() {
        ExecutionContextPromotionListener listener = new ExecutionContextPromotionListener();
        listener.setKeys(new String[] {"COUNTRY", "CATEGORY", "USER"});
        return listener;
    }



    /*Country Step*/

    @JobScope
    @Bean
    public MongoItemReader<COUNTRY> CountryItemReader(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['COUNTRY']}") HashMap<String, Object> table) {
       int date = (int) table.get("date");
        MongoItemReader<COUNTRY> reader = new MongoItemReader<COUNTRY>();
        reader.setTemplate(mongoTemplate);
        reader.setTargetType(COUNTRY.class);
        reader.setCollection("COUNTRY");
        reader.setFields("{\"COUNTRY_NAME\": 1,\"SHORT_NAME\": 1,\"DEPT_CODE\": 1}");
        reader.setSort(new HashMap<String, Sort.Direction>() {{
            put("_id", Sort.Direction.DESC);
        }});
        reader.setQuery("{DATE_TIME: {$gt:"+date+"}}");
        reader.setPageSize(250);
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public CountryItemProcessor CountryProcessor(){
        return new CountryItemProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaItemWriter<COUNTRY> country_writer(){
        JpaItemWriter<COUNTRY> jpa = new JpaItemWriter<COUNTRY>();
        jpa.setEntityManagerFactory(em.getEntityManagerFactory());
        return jpa;
    }


    @JobScope
    @Bean
    public Step step1(@Value("#{jobExecutionContext['COUNTRY']}") HashMap<String, Object> tab) {
        int size = (int) tab.get("size");
        //System.out.println(size);
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("step1")
                .<COUNTRY, COUNTRY>chunk(20)
                .reader(CountryItemReader(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
                .writer(country_writer())
                .build();
    }



    @Bean
    public Job TestJob(Step stepConfig) throws Exception {

        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("TestJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())// because a spring config bug, this incrementer is not really useful
                .start(stepConfig)
                .next(step1(OVERRIDDEN_BY_EXPRESSION))
               
                .build();
    }

}
```

However when adding `SimpleAsyncTaskExecutor` an error occured:

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ScopeNotActiveException: Error creating bean with name 'scopedTarget.CountryItemReader': Scope 'job' is not active for the current thread; consider defining a scoped proxy for this bean if you intend to refer to it from a singleton; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:383) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.target.SimpleBeanTargetSource.getTarget(SimpleBeanTargetSource.java:35) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:676) ~[spring-aop-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.data.MongoItemReader$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$67443e4.read(<generated>) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.doRead(SimpleChunkProvider.java:99) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.read(SimpleChunkProvider.java:180) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:126) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider.provide(SimpleChunkProvider.java:118) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:71) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate$ExecutingRunnable.run(TaskExecutorRepeatTemplate.java:262) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:829) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No context holder available for job scope
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.getContext(JobScope.java:159) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.JobScope.get(JobScope.java:92) ~[spring-batch-core-4.3.2.jar:4.3.2]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:371) ~[spring-beans-5.3.6.jar:5.3.6]
```

I tried solving this issue like in:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1335, but it seems like it is using just one thread in addition to the main.

Is there any way to resolve this issue without adding tweaked code ?

I'm planning to scale the job using remote partitionning on Kubernetes, would this issue persist because of job scope?

Any thoughts or advice are more than welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I'm trying to share data between steps using JobExecutionContext, which works only if i keep the steps single threaded

Relying on the execution context to share data between multi-threaded steps is incorrect, because the keys will be overridden by concurrent threads. The reference documentation explicitly mentions to turn off state management in multi-threaded environment:

- [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html): `remember to use saveState=false if used in a multi-threaded client`
- [Reference doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.3.x/reference/html/step.html#late-binding): `it is not recommended to use job-scoped beans in multi-threaded or partitioned steps`

That said, I don't see what key could be shared from a multi-threaded step to the next step (as threads are executed in parallel), but if you really need to do that, you should use another method like defining a shared bean that is thread safe.

Comment: Thank you, but how to define a thread safe shared bean ?

Comment: For example by creating a class that holds a thread-safe data structure (like a `ConcurrentHashMap` for example) and define an instance of it as a bean.

Comment: That's actually what i did, except i still have a few questions: 1- Can i use a variable inside the step method like a variable to define chunk size dynamically ? 2- does using multithreaded steps affect restartability ?

Comment: 1. Yes, and you did right by making your step job-scoped so that the creation of that step bean is delayed and only done at runtime. 2. It depends: the issue that might happen is that concurrent threads override each others restart data in the execution context (read.count, write.count, etc), but if you manage to prevent this, then you can preserve restartability.

Comment: What do you recommend to preserve the restartability, since it's crucial for my usecase.

Comment: The recommendation depends on the use case, but an efficient way to get restartability with a multi-threaded step is to use a stateless reader/writer (ie not rely on the execution context at all) and use the process indicator pattern to mark records as processed or not. In a failure scenario, only unprocessed records would be processed. You can find an example here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/main/spring-batch-samples/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/sample/common/StagingItemReader.java.